# Declaring global variable from DataStore

Tags: extjs

I would like to declare a global variable that takes value from DataStore.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        id: 'ID_myStore',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: 'get.php',      
                method: 'POST'
            }),
        baseParams:{task: "LIST"}, 
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({   
                    root: 'results',
                    totalProperty: 'total',
                    id: 'id'
                },[ 
                   {name: 'Class', type: 'string', mapping: 'class'}
              ])
    });

        var BestClass = myStore.getAt(0).get('Class');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ooo an async problem.

You need to listen to the callback, and then do it.

```
var myStore = new Ext.dataStore({......
});
var bestClass;
myStore.on('load',function(store,record){
 bestClass = store.getAt(0).get('Class');
},this)
```

Note, that whilst that is the answer as to how to do it, it doesnt get called at the same time as everything else, its an event ( which you listen to ), so that variable will be undefined until the server has responded.

Comment: It does not work. When you change 'var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({' with 'var myStore = new Ext.dataStore({', I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)ooo.html:33
call"